# How to regex_replace in smarty?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, smarty3

I'm trying to do a regex_replace in smarty, I have tied the following, yet it prints the variable name, does not return the variable value.

How do I replace with `$another`?

#### Attempt

```
{$title|regex_replace:"/apple/":"{$another}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, we might not want to have `{$another}`, and we can try:

```
{assign var="p_open" value="<p class='bla'>"}
{assign var="p_text" value=$another.xyz}
{assign var="p_close" value="</p>"}
{assign var="replace" value=$p_open$p_text$p_close}

{$title|regex_replace:"/(apple)/":$replace}
```

#### [Reference](https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=9432)

Comment: the last one filtered but my replace has {$title|regex_replace:"/apple/":'<p class="bla">{$another}</p>'}, how would be work the var if there tag, class?

Comment: another is global var, the anther var have value as orange. so i want to use var because the var is language mode and when other language, the var will auto detect the value from var

Comment: my {$another} var like this. {$another.zyz}

Comment: You assign multiple var that causes issue. if single var, then working. like {assign var="replace" value=$another.xyz}

Answer (score 0):

The correct validation. You need add and close with " (quotation) marks on replace var to work properly for this case.

```
{assign var="p_open" value="<p class='bla'>"}
{assign var="p_text" value=$another.xyz}
{assign var="p_close" value="</p>"}
{assign var="replace" value="$p_open$p_text$p_close"}

{$title|regex_replace:"/(apple)/":$replace}
```